# Auto attaching space tug or truck for Artemis

Tags: artemis-1

So Artemis 1 completed a crucial burn yesterday to send it back to Earth for splashdown on Sunday: https://www.space.com/artemis-1-orion-spacecraft-on-track-to-return-to-Earth

Maybe I am just a dark guy, but what if this burn did not happen and we needed to reach out to the capsule in space. Are there any kind of rockets or space tugs that can be deployed in an emergency to reach out and attach to the capsule and tug it back home? Any such things on the drawing board anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Yes. Space tug concepts are on the drawing board as well as operational. But nothing that can arrive in Lunar orbit on short notice like an [AAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Automobile_Association) tow truck dispatch. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tug.

Here is one concept from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242421321_Near-Future_Reusable_Space_Logistics_Vehicles/figures?lo=1

[image]

One problem is grappling and docking with the "client" spacecraft, especially if it is uncooperative. The docking must be secure enough to tolerate thrust, and ideally the thrust line should be through the center of mass of the client craft. Two possible solutions:

1. A "stinger" probe that locks into the throat of the client rocket bell
2. Docking to the mounting ring that attached the client to its top stage

Comment: Note that this space tug may push only, but seagoing tugboats mostly pull and sometimes push.